# "go well" vs "went well" in the past tense

Tags: past-tense, do-support

Which of the following is correct?

> 1. Did everything go well?
> 2. Did everything went well?

Intuitively I think it is 1). But one my colleagues asked me to explain the reasoning, and I am unable to do so. Also

> 1. Everything went well?
> 2. Everything go well?

Now intuitively, I think it is 1).

How come addition of "Did" changes the "go" to "went". Which rule are we following here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various ways of expressing past tense:

1. Use a simple verb in past tense: "It went well."
2. Use an auxiliary verb in past tense, with the main verb in the infinitive. "It did go well." Since "did" is already past tense, you do not change "go" to past tense.
3. Use the past perfect, with the past tense of "have", and the past participle of the main verb. "It has gone well." In English, the past perfect doesn't have exactly the same meaning as the simple past.

In your second examples, "Everything went well?" is a declarative sentence with a question mark (or raised tone), turning it into a question. "Everything go well?" is just a contraction of "*Did* everything go well?", and so is also correct in casual usage.

Answer (score 0):

This example  is a beginners class:

Did every thing go well ?

Everything went well?
This sentence is used incorrectly,  is not a question is an answer. Used here incorrectly and making  it confusing for all learners.

Question: Did everything go well ?

Answer: Everything went well

Is a question the gramatical extructure is correct
DID EVERYTHING GO WELL?
DID = past simple of DO , use to ask question for things that happened in the past
GO= present simple